# Как изменить язык в Jupyter notebook с китайского на русский или английский?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

[image: В некоторых местах китайские иероглифы]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом я могу исправить данную проблему. Сразу после установки язык стал китайским... буду вам очень благодарен.

Comment: можно попробовать изменить язык браузера, либо [перед запуском jupyter выполнять `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4158)

Comment: Китайский язык оказался первым среди моих предпочтений в Гугле XD. Смена языка в браузере помогла, спасибо.